# I have attach AWS volume to EC2 instance, but i can't see volume in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have recently create and attach AWS volume `nvme1n1` to EC2 instance, but i can see volume in console.

On running `lsblk` in aws-cli ->

```
nvme0n1     098:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 098:1    0   8G  0 part /
nvme1n1     098:2    0   5G  0 disk <---------- can't see this one !
```

On running `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           772M  780K  771M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  2.8G  5.0G  37% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/62004
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/14466
tmpfs           772M     0  772M   0% /run/user/42423
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attaching a volume to an instance you should **format** and **mount** it:

- [Format and mount an attached volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html#ebs-format-mount-volume)

Since you haven't mentioned performing these steps, it seems that you haven't done them.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html